# Setting the target version of Java in ant javac

Tags: ant, javac

I need to compile a jar file using ant (1.7.0) to run under a specific version of Java (1.5). I currently have Java 1.6 on my machine. I have tried setting:

```
<target name="compile">
  <javac compiler="javac1.5" target="1.5" srcdir=.../>
</target>
```

I have also removed

```
<property name="build.compiler" value="modern"/>
```

and there is no properties file. I am running Java 1.6 on Linux/SUSE

Also is there a simple way of determining which version of Java is expected in the jar file.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use "target" attribute and remove the 'compiler' attribute. See [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html). So it should go something like this:

```
<target name="compile">
  <javac target="1.5" srcdir=.../>
</target>
```

Comment: I had to use source and bootclasspath attributes as well. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#examples) for a cross compilation example. (there is direct correspondence with the ant attributes)

Comment: It would be really nice if the answer could be modified to add `source` and `bootclasspath`

Comment: it helps with a legacy app.

Comment: <javac target="15"

Answer (score 50):

Both source and target should be specified. I recommend providing [ant defaults](http://ant.apache.org/manual/javacprops.html#source), that way you do not need to specify source/target attribute for every javac task:

```
<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.5"/>
<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.5"/>
```

See [Java cross-compiling notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-example) for more information.

Comment: <property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="15"/>
<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="15"/>

Answer (score 15):

To find the version of the java in the classfiles I used:

```
javap -verbose <classname>
```

which announces the version at the start as

```
minor version: 0
major version: 49
```

which corresponds to Java 1.5

Answer (score 5):

You may also set `{{ant.build.javac.target=1.5}}` ant property to update default target version of  task. 
See http://ant.apache.org/manual/javacprops.html#target

Comment: {{ant.build.javac.target=15}}