# Use Java 1.4 for compilation in Ant

Tags: java, ant

I have some old Java source code that raises an error in ant.

```
[javac]             Enumeration enum = props.propertyNames();
[javac]                         ^
[javac]   (use -source 1.4 or lower to use 'enum' as an identifier)
```

How can I teach ANT to use `-source 1.4`?

Comment: OR, you could rename that local var to something different from enum, e.g. propEnum. You are getting this warning just because you are using what is essentially a reserved keyword in java 1.5+, with a javac 1.5+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Javac` task has `source` and `target` properties to specify JVM version...

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

as in something like the following in your `build.xml`...

```
<javac source="1.4" target="1.4" ...>
```

Comment: +1, Answered here as well if you need an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487978/setting-the-target-version-of-java-in-ant-javac