# How to build a jar with different java version with ANT

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I tried to build a jar file using java 1.5. I use eclise and I specified the java version as 1.5 in below areas.

- Project -> Properties ->  Java Compiler
- Project -> Java Build Path -> JRE System Library
- Ant Build File -> Run As -> ExternalToolConfiguration -> JRE

But after the jar is built all the classes were built in 1.7 (major version 51) I want them in 1.5.(49)
This is the result for `javap -verbose MyClassInBuiltJar`

```
SourceFile: "Program.java"
minor version: 0
major version: 51
Constant pool:
```

Comment: Have you checked this [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487978/setting-the-target-version-of-java-in-ant-javac[/link]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not ANT that cause the issue, you may need to change the project's `JRE` and recompile the project with the `1.5 JRE`.

You can also try to specify the JRE used directly in your `build.xml` file.

Comment: You are true semihyagcioglu. It wasn't an ANT issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use source=1.5 and target=1.5 in javac ant task.
See here for details [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly specify the source and target in the build.xml:

```
<property name="javac.source"  value="1.5"/>
<property name="javac.target"  value="1.5"/>
<javac source="${javac.source}"  target="${javac.target}">
```

Comment: Thanx tigran for the support.